# Initialization error using custom classes C++

Tags: c++, list, class, initialization

I keep getting the error on the "Rainfall most = NULL;" line when trying to initalize. Cannot convert int to Rainfall. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. There are four files total and I'll really appreciate any help.

MAIN

```
    // This program demonstrates the linked list template.
#include <iostream>
#include "RainfallList.h"
#include "Rainfall.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Define a LinkedList object.
    RainfallList<Rainfall> list;
    Rainfall most = NULL;
    //Rainfall least = NULL;
    int entries = 0;
    bool marker = false;
    int month = 0;
    int year = 0;
    double rainfall = 0.0;
    double total = 0.0;

    cout << "Enter the number of entries you would like: ";
    cin >> entries;

    //Create linked list of values
    for(int i=1; i<=entries; i++){

        marker=false;

        while(marker==false){
            cout << "Enter the month for entry " << i << " (1-12): ";
            cin >> month;

            cout << "Enter the year for entry " << i << " (2010-2013): ";
            cin >> year;

            cout << "Enter the rainfall for entry " << i << " (inches): ";
            cin >> rainfall;

            if(month>0 && month<13 && year>2009 && year<2014 && rainfall>=0){
                marker=true;
            }else{
                cout << endl << endl << "**ERROR** Make sure the month is a value from 1-12, the year is 2010-2013, and rainfall is 0 or greater!" << endl << endl;
            }

        }

        Rainfall value(year, month, rainfall);
        list.appendNode(value);
    }


    list.displayList();


    //find average rainfall
    total = list.getAvg();

    cout << "The total amount of rainfall is " << total << " inches." << endl;

    cout << "The average rainfall is " << total/entries << " inches" << endl;


    //find the month with the highest rainfall
    most = list.getMost();

    cout << "The most rainfall happened in " << most.getMonth() << " of " << most.getYear() << " where it rained " << most.getRainfall() << " inches." << endl;


    //find the month with the lowest rainfall
    most = list.getLeast();

    cout << "The most rainfall happened in " << most.getMonth() << " of " << most.getYear() << " where it rained " << most.getRainfall() << " inches." << endl;

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

LINKEDLIST

```
// A class template for holding a linked list.
// The node type is also a class template.
#ifndef RainfallList_H
#define RainfallList_H

#include "Rainfall.h"

//*********************************************
// The ListNode class creates a type used to  *
// store a node of the linked list.           *
//*********************************************

template <class T>
class RainfallListNode
{
public:
    T value;           // Node value
    RainfallListNode<T> *next; // Pointer to the next node

    // Constructor
    RainfallListNode(T nodeValue)
    {
        value = nodeValue;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

//*********************************************
// LinkedList class                           *
//*********************************************

template <class T>
class RainfallList:Rainfall
{
private:
    RainfallListNode<T> *head;   // List head pointer

public:
    // Constructor
    RainfallList()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }

    // Destructor
    ~RainfallList();

    // Linked list operations
    void appendNode(T);
    void insertNode(T);
    void deleteNode(T);
    void displayList() const;
    double getAvg();
    Rainfall getMost();
    Rainfall getLeast();
};


//**************************************************
// appendNode appends a node containing the value  *
// pased into newValue, to the end of the list.    *
//**************************************************

template <class T>
void RainfallList<T>::appendNode(T newValue)
{
    RainfallListNode<T> *newNode;  // To point to a new node
    RainfallListNode<T> *nodePtr;  // To move through the list

    // Allocate a new node and store newValue there.
    newNode = new RainfallListNode<T>(newValue);

    // If there are no nodes in the list
    // make newNode the first node.
    if (!head)
        head = newNode;
    else  // Otherwise, insert newNode at end.
    {
        // Initialize nodePtr to head of list.
        nodePtr = head;

        // Find the last node in the list.
        while (nodePtr->next)
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;

        // Insert newNode as the last node.
        nodePtr->next = newNode;
    }
}

//**************************************************
// displayList shows the value stored in each node *
// of the linked list pointed to by head.          *
//**************************************************

template <class T>
void RainfallList<T>::displayList() const
{
    RainfallListNode<T> *nodePtr;  // To move through the list

    // Position nodePtr at the head of the list.
    nodePtr = head;

    // While nodePtr points to a node, traverse
    // the list.
    while (nodePtr)
    {
        // Display the value in this node.
        cout << nodePtr->value << endl;

        // Move to the next node.
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }
}

//**************************************************
// The insertNode function inserts a node with     *
// newValue copied to its value member.            *
//**************************************************

template <class T>
void RainfallList<T>::insertNode(T newValue)
{
    RainfallListNode<T> *newNode;             // A new node
    RainfallListNode<T> *nodePtr;             // To traverse the list
    RainfallListNode<T> *previousNode = NULL; // The previous node

    // Allocate a new node and store newValue there.
    newNode = new RainfallListNode<T>(newValue);

    // If there are no nodes in the list
    // make newNode the first node
    if (!head)
    {
        head = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    else  // Otherwise, insert newNode
    {
        // Position nodePtr at the head of list.
        nodePtr = head;

        // Initialize previousNode to NULL.
        previousNode = NULL;

        // Skip all nodes whose value is less than newValue.
        while (nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr->value < newValue)
        {
            previousNode = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }

        // If the new node is to be the 1st in the list,
        // insert it before all other nodes.
        if (previousNode == NULL)
        {
            head = newNode;
            newNode->next = nodePtr;
        }
        else  // Otherwise insert after the previous node.
        {
            previousNode->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = nodePtr;
        }
    }
}

//*****************************************************
// The deleteNode function searches for a node        *
// with searchValue as its value. The node, if found, *
// is deleted from the list and from memory.          *
//*****************************************************

template <class T>
void RainfallList<T>::deleteNode(T searchValue)
{
    RainfallListNode<T> *nodePtr;       // To traverse the list
    RainfallListNode<T> *previousNode = nullptr;  // To point to the previous node

    // If the list is empty, do nothing.
    if (!head)
        return;

    // Determine if the first node is the one.
    if (head->value == searchValue)
    {
        nodePtr = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = nodePtr;
    }
    else
    {
        // Initialize nodePtr to head of list
        nodePtr = head;

        // Skip all nodes whose value member is 
        // not equal to num.
        while (nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr->value != searchValue)
        {
            previousNode = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }

        // If nodePtr is not at the end of the list, 
        // link the previous node to the node after
        // nodePtr, then delete nodePtr.
        if (nodePtr)
        {
            previousNode->next = nodePtr->next;
            delete nodePtr;
        }
    }
}

//**************************************************
// Destructor                                      *
// This function deletes every node in the list.   *
//**************************************************

template <class T>
RainfallList<T>::~RainfallList()
{
    RainfallListNode<T> *nodePtr;   // To traverse the list
    RainfallListNode<T> *nextNode;  // To point to the next node

    // Position nodePtr at the head of the list.
    nodePtr = head;

    // While nodePtr is not at the end of the list...
    while (nodePtr != NULL)
    {
        // Save a pointer to the next node.
        nextNode = nodePtr->next;

        // Delete the current node.
        delete nodePtr;

        // Position nodePtr at the next node.
        nodePtr = nextNode;
    }
}

template <class T>
double RainfallList<T>::getAvg()
{
    double avg = 0.0;
    Rainfall obj;

    RainfallListNode<T> *nodePtr;  // To move through the list

    // Position nodePtr at the head of the list.
    nodePtr = head;

    // While nodePtr points to a node, traverse
    // the list.
    while (nodePtr)
    {
        // Display the value in this node.
        //cout << nodePtr->value << endl;
        obj = nodePtr->value;
        avg += obj.getRainfall();

        // Move to the next node.
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }

    return avg;
}

template <class T>
Rainfall RainfallList<T>::getMost()
{
    //double avg = 0.0;
    Rainfall obj = NULL;
    Rainfall obj2 = NULL;


    RainfallListNode<T> *nodePtr;  // To move through the list

    // Position nodePtr at the head of the list.
    nodePtr = head;

    obj = nodePtr->value;

    // While nodePtr points to a node, traverse
    // the list.
    while (nodePtr)
    {
        // Display the value in this node.
        //cout << nodePtr->value << endl;
        obj2 = nodePtr->value;

        if (obj.getRainfall() < obj2.getRainfall()){
            obj = nodePtr->value;
        }

        // Move to the next node.
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }

    return obj;
}

template <class T>
Rainfall RainfallList<T>::getLeast()
{
    //double avg = 0.0;
    Rainfall obj = NULL;
    Rainfall obj2 = NULL;

    RainfallListNode<T> *nodePtr;  // To move through the list

    // Position nodePtr at the head of the list.
    nodePtr = head;

    obj = nodePtr->value;

    // While nodePtr points to a node, traverse
    // the list.
    while (nodePtr)
    {
        // Display the value in this node.
        //cout << nodePtr->value << endl;
        obj2 = nodePtr->value;

        if (obj.getRainfall() > obj2.getRainfall()){
            obj = nodePtr->value;
        }

        // Move to the next node.
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }

    return obj;
}

#endif
```

RAINFALL CLASS

```
#ifndef RAINFALL_H
#define RAINFALL_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


//class rainclass;      

//ostream &operator << (ostream & , const Rainfall & );
//istream &operator >> (istream & , Rainfall & );

class Rainfall
{
private:
    int year;
    int month;
    double rainfall;

public:
    Rainfall(void);

    Rainfall(int year, int month, double rainfall);

    void setRain(int year, int month, double rainfall);

    int getYear();

    int getMonth();

    double getRainfall();

    void print();


    // Overloaded operator functions
    Rainfall operator + (const Rainfall &); // Overloaded +
    //Rainfall operator - (const Rainfall &); // Overloaded -
    //Rainfall operator ++ ();                  // Prefix ++
    //Rainfall operator ++ (int);               // Postfix ++
    bool operator > (const Rainfall &);     // Overloaded >
    bool operator < (const Rainfall &);     // Overloaded <
    //bool operator == (const Rainfall &);      // Overloaded ==
    //bool operator != (const Rainfall &);      // Overloaded ==

    // Conversion functions
    //operator double();
    //operator int();

    // Friends
    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &, const Rainfall &);
    //friend istream &operator >> (istream &, Rainfall &);

};
#endif
```

RAINFALL IMPLEMENTATION

```
#include "Rainfall.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Rainfall::Rainfall(){
    year = 0;
    month = 0;
    rainfall = 0.0;
}

Rainfall::Rainfall(int tempyear, int tempmonth, double temprainfall){
    year = tempyear;
    month = tempmonth;
    rainfall = temprainfall;
}

void Rainfall::setRain(int tempyear, int tempmonth, double temprainfall){
    year = tempyear;
    month = tempmonth;
    rainfall = temprainfall;
}

int Rainfall::getMonth() {
    return month;
}

int Rainfall::getYear() {
    return year;
}

double Rainfall::getRainfall() {
    return rainfall;
}

void Rainfall::print() {
    cout << "There was " << getRainfall() << " inches of rainfall in " << getMonth() << " of " << getYear() << endl;
}

//**********************************************
// Overloaded binary + operator.               *
//**********************************************

Rainfall Rainfall::operator + (const Rainfall &right)
{
    Rainfall temp;

    //temp.year = year + right.year;
    //temp.month = month + right.month;
    temp.rainfall = rainfall + right.rainfall;
    return temp;
}

//********************************************************
// Overloaded << operator. Gives cout the ability to     *
// directly display FeetInches objects.                  *
//********************************************************

ostream &operator<<(ostream &strm, const Rainfall &obj)
{
    strm << obj.month << "  " << obj.year << "  " << obj.rainfall << "inches" << endl;
    return strm;
}

//************************************************************
// Overloaded > operator. Returns true if the current object *
// is set to a value greater than that of right.             *
//************************************************************

bool Rainfall::operator > (const Rainfall &right)
{
    bool status;

    if (rainfall > right.rainfall)
        status = true;
    //else if (feet == right.feet && inches > right.inches)
        //status = true;
    else
        status = false;

    return status;
}

//************************************************************
// Overloaded < operator. Returns true if the current object *
// is set to a value less than that of right.                *
//************************************************************

bool Rainfall::operator < (const Rainfall &right)
{
    bool status;

    if (rainfall < right.rainfall)
        status = true;
    //else if (feet == right.feet && inches < right.inches)
        //status = true;
    else
        status = false;

    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize a pointer with NULL, but assigning NULL (which is an int behind the scenes) to an object (`Rainfall` in your case) makes no sense.

```
Rainfall most;
```

is enough, because your Rainfall constructor is already initialising the new object with zeros by default.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just got hardcore tunnel vision. Simplest fix so far on this.